# Rails how to google translate database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible somehow to create a solution that can google translate a whole database?

It is very time consuming to translate each individual data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Translate service is available as an API, but is no longer free http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html.

Comment: This should work. Just be aware that you'd be leaving the quality of translations up to an API, rather than intelligent humans. If that's okay (and/or you plan to spot check the translations, and are just using this for automation) then you should be fine.